# NSFetchRequest from Template - Xcode 5 Editor Rewrites Expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode5

I'm trying to create a fetch request template for `MyMessage` objects that have a nil `whenRead` date property and a recipient with a given `userID`. However, when I try to create such an expression in the Xcode 5 fetch request editor, it converts my expression from this:

[image: desired predicate]

to this (using the current date as the value):

[image: rewritten predicate]

after I click away and select the request tab again.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is this an Xcode 5 bug, or am I missing something here?

(The `whenRead` property is marked as optional and has a date type.)

EDIT:

I should add that when I create this predicate programmatically, it works just fine.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Message"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipient.userID == %@ AND whenRead == %@", userID, [NSNull null]]];
```

Comment: Not sure, but I suggest trying "0" in the predicate editor instead of "nil".

Comment: Using a "0" has the same effect. Leaving the two clauses and THEN  adding a "0" changes the previous whenRead clause to an "is not" and adds a new "is" clause (both with today's date).

Comment: FWIW I've file this as a bug and it's also available in Open Radar: http://www.openradar.me/16037400

Comment: Awesome, I had been meaning to do so but never got around to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have hit a limitation in IB. Use the following method of NSManagedObjectModel to define the fetch request template when your app launches:

```
setFetchRequestTemplate:forName:
```

This still gives you the speed of a fetch template but also provides the ability to set that nil equality. I'd file a Radar about this too; IB should definitely allow nil values.